# Space complexity of the piece of code below?

Tags: java, space-complexity

I came across this question while I was doing some interview prep.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // n is some user input value
        int i = 0;
        while (i < n) {
            int[] a = new int[n];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                a[j] = i * j;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The choices given were:

1. O(n)
2. O(n^2)

From what I understand the answer should have been O(n) as on every iteration a new instance of the array is being created and the previous reference is being lost. However, the book mentions the answer to be O(n^2).

What could be a possible explanation?

Comment: The algorithm would not necessarily complete successfully with constant amount of memory, as the user could enter an arbitrarily large `n` in this case. (Disregarding from the maximum value of an `int` and so on.)

When analyzing complexity you look at the algorithm, and typically don't take JVM specific implementation details such as garbage collection algorithms into account. This algorithm allocates an array of size `n`, `n` times. Space complexity is therefore O(n).

Comment: In this specific case, I would even argue that the JIT would realize that `a` is a loop local variable and `n` doesn't change in the loop so perhaps the same array is even reused each iteration.

Comment: @aioobe "[You] typically don't take JVM specific implementation details such as garbage collection algorithms into account" - wouldn't that mean that we'd have to assume the arrays are never released and thus we'd need O(n^2) memory? Or do you refer to the specific algorithms only?

Comment: @Thomas, I would argue that, by Java language semantics, the array allocated in iteration 1, is to be considered free memory as iteration 1 falls off the edge of the loop body and iteration 2 starts.

Comment: OP, you'd have to give more context if you want a definitive answer. What exactly was said about O(n^2) in the book? Without this all you will get is wild speculations.

Comment: @aioobe The section was about `Algorithm Complexity` and the choice of language was Java. I had mailed the author, to which the response was "We have to consider how much memory is being consumed for that piece of code at that time, garbage collection may happen later but we are not sure when.", which I personally find incorrect.

Comment: I believe the author is explaining everything in terms of JAVA, but again he/she is conceptually wrong there. As a programmer, I shouldn't have to worry about garbage collection. (which I understand can get tricky in production systems)

Comment: Yes. I would say that reasoning is flawed. You should let him/her know that memory eligible for garbage collection can for all intents an purposes be considered free. If he wants to take account for GC details, he/she is in a world of pain, since there are many different GC algorithms and many different GC options to consider. Or even better, pass him/her a link to this question :-) Maybe he/she can provide an answer for us all.

Comment: @aioobe That's sometimes a problem. People get offended if you doubt their reasoning XD, especially technical!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

Your explanation is correct. The space complexity is **linear**.

However, your conclusion (and the conclusion of the books author) is wrong. The correct answer is that **both** answers are correct. That is, the space complexity is in both:

- `O(n)` and
- `O(n^2)`

Big-O gives an upper-bound, not the exact bound. Think about it as `<=` as opposed to just `=`. So if `a in O(n)` it is also true that `a in O(n^2)` (mathematically, Big-O gives a set of functions).

The exact bound is given by **Theta** (`=`) and a lower bound by *Omega* (`>=`), a strict lower bound is given by *small-omega* (`>`) and a strict upper bound by *small-o* (`<`). So the space complexity is in `Theta(n)`.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for more information and the actual mathematical definitions.

---

### Notes

The space complexity is only **linear** if we assume that Javas garbage collector is **active**. It is possible to disable it or replace it by a mock implementation which does not actually free memory (see the [Epsilon-GC](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/318)).

In that case, the space complexity would indeed be **quadratic**.

The algorithm itself needs to **allocate** a quadratic amount of memory. However, it will only ever hold a **linear** amount of memory at the same time. Space complexity analysis is typically done with respect to how much memory must be hold at the same time. But maybe the author wanted to analyze the algorithm with respect to how much needs to be allocated in total, which could also explain his choice.

Comment: I don't think the book would mention O(n^2) for space complexity, just because O(n) is a subset of O(n^2). That's a mathematical formality. With that argument, it's in O(n!) and O(n^n) as well. When you talk about Big-O you typically typically talk about worst-case and not worse-than-worst case.

Comment: Big-O analysis is often just an educated guess for a tight bound. It is pretty common that people do not find the real actual tight bound but just give a "close enough bound" using Big-O. An actual bound analysis always includes Omega and thus yielding a correct Theta bound. At least when we are talking about scientific publications. Maybe the book has a different audience and thus is not really precise.

Comment: In this case I think O(n) can be considered a tight bound and not just an educated guess.

Comment: That is indeed a detailed answer covering all aspects. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but you can't say `O(n)` is equivalent to `O(n²)`, also garbage collection has nothing to do with Big O notation as the algorithm's complexity should be language agnostic

Comment: @YassinHajaj I did not say that `O(n) = O(n^2)`, I did say that any function that is element of the set `O(n)` is also element of the set `O(n^2)`, because `O(n)` is a subset of `O(n^2)`. I agree to the garbage collection, it is still an interesting thing to note though when translating the results of a performance analysis into real world. And it is not uncommon to do an analysis with respect to garbage collection and other real world effects.

Answer (score 1):

The book seems to simply have it wrong. The required space to execute is O(n). As to the possible explanation: the author had runtime complexity in mind. The nested loop gives a O(n^2) runtime complexity. If the book is somewhat recent and popular, it may have an errata webpage, which might shed light on it.

Comment: I would argue that it is not defined since the behaviour of the memory allocation process is not known or defined. Each defererencing and subsequent allocation of the array could allocate new memory or re-use old memory, depending on optimisations, how the memory manager works, the garbage collector in use and gc parameters.

Comment: @rghome, the only authoritative reference when discussing _Java_ questions is the _Java_ Language Specification. According to this spec, memory that is eligible for garbage collection is for all intents and purposes considered to be free.

Comment: It does not strike me as a trick question. Reasonable assumptions should be allowed.

Comment: Technically, something that is in `O(n)` is also in `O(n^2)`. This is a correct statement. The exact bound is given by `Theta`, not by Big-O.

Comment: @aioobe We all know that "free" memory still consumes space and requires physical memory until it has been re-used or compacted. The fact that Java thinks it is free is only one perspective.